# [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001EE, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: '' ]; remaining name ''

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

In my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I override the configure method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchBase("DC=unit1,DC=org1,DC=com")
            .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
            .contextSource().url(ldapUrl).managerDn(mgrDn).managerPassword(mgrPassword);
}
```

I am passing the following request:

Request Headers: `Content-Type: application/x-www.form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`
Form Data `username=user&password=password`

But I keep on getting the ldap error.  Please advise.

Comment: i highly recommend using ldaps as opposed to ldap. all of your ldap traffic is practically clear  on the network. something to consider.

Comment: will this solve my issue?

Comment: there are a lof of missing pieces in your code ( how is the ldap code being called, etc ). it’s unlikely that it will, but it will certainly make it more secure